# MySQL - selecting all rooms including partial date ranges

Tags: mysql, date, join, select

Im currently have room availability present which displays current open rooms for bookings given a specified date range.

I need to display the same availability but instead of displaying rooms for the FULL availability i need to show partial availability.

```
Eg: booking 1 is from dates 22nd to 25th (within room 4)
booking 2 is from dates 24th to 28th (within room 3)
queried booking is from 23rd till 25th

22nd    23rd  24th     25th      28th
|-----------------------|
               |------------------|
        |------|                    free space
```

query:

```
SELECT r.*
     , CASE WHEN b.ref IS NULL THEN 'all' ELSE 'partial' END status
  FROM roominfo r 
  LEFT JOIN bookroom br ON br.id = r.id 
  LEFT JOIN book b ON b.ref = br.ref 
  AND b.end_date >= '2019-11-23' AND b.start_date <= '2019-11-25'
 ORDERBY r.id;
```

example structure & data:

```
 CREATE SCHEMA TEST;
USE TEST;

CREATE TABLE BOOK( Ref INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Start_Date DATE NOT NULL, End_Date DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Ref));
CREATE TABLE ROOMINFO( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `Type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Max TINYINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE BOOKROOM( Ref INT NOT NULL,ID INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Ref) REFERENCES BOOK(Ref), FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES ROOMINFO(ID));

INSERT INTO BOOK(Start_Date, End_Date) VALUES   
('2019-11-22', '2019-11-25'),('2019-11-24', '2019-11-28'),('2019-12-01', '2019-12-02'),('2019-12-01', '2019-12-06'),
('2019-12-02', '2019-12-03'),('2019-12-04', '2019-12-10'),('2019-12-04', '2019-12-10'),('2019-12-05', '2019-12-13'),
('2019-12-16', '2019-12-19'),('2019-12-26', '2019-12-28'),('2019-12-26', '2020-01-01'),('2019-12-28', '2020-01-02'),
('2019-12-31', '2020-01-05'),('2020-01-03', '2020-01-08'),('2020-01-05', '2020-01-11'),('2020-01-06', '2020-01-09'),
('2020-01-06', '2020-01-11'),('2020-01-08', '2020-01-18'),('2020-01-11', '2020-01-15'),('2020-01-15', '2020-01-17'),
('2020-01-15', '2020-01-18');

INSERT INTO ROOMINFO (ID, `Type`,Max) VALUES
(1, "Family", 4), (2, "Family", 4), (3, "Family", 4), (4, "Dual", 2),
(5, "Dual", 2),   (6, "Dual", 2), (7, "Dual", 2),   (8, "Dual", 2),
(9, "Dual", 2),   (10, "Dual", 2);

INSERT INTO BOOKROOM( Ref, ID ) VALUES
(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5),(5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1), (10, 8),(11, 3), 
(12, 9), (13, 2), (14, 10), (15, 4), (16, 5), (17, 6), (18, 7), (19, 2),(20, 1), (21, 10);
```

desired output:

```
id    (& some indication of partial availability?)
1  all
2  all
3  partial
4  partial
5  all
6  all
7  all
8  all
9  all
10  all
```

Comment: What should the desired result look  like?

Comment: It seems that every room satisfies the condition. Is that a sensible example?

Comment: @Strawberry I have added the desired results, the query does not show room 4 & 3 because they are counted as within the queried date range

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the distressing naming policy...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;

CREATE TABLE BOOK( Ref INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Start_Date DATE NOT NULL, End_Date DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Ref));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS roominfo;
CREATE TABLE ROOMINFO( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `Type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, capacity TINYINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookroom;
CREATE TABLE BOOKROOM( Ref INT NOT NULL,ID INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO BOOK(Start_Date, End_Date) VALUES   
("2019-11-03", "2019-11-10"), ("2019-11-05", "2019-11-13");

INSERT INTO ROOMINFO (ID, `Type`,capacity) VALUES
(1, "Family", 4), (2, "Family", 4), (3, "Family", 4), (4, "Dual", 2),
(5, "Dual", 2),   (6, "Dual", 2), (7, "Dual", 2),   (8, "Dual", 2),
(9, "Dual", 2),   (10, "Dual", 2);

INSERT INTO BOOKROOM( Ref, ID ) VALUES (1, 4), (2, 3);

SELECT r.*
     , CASE WHEN b.ref IS NULL THEN 'all' ELSE 'partial' END status
  FROM roominfo r 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookroom br 
    ON br.id = r.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN book b 
    ON b.ref = br.ref 
   AND b.end_date >= '2019-11-01' AND b.start_date <= '2019-11-13'
 ORDER
    BY r.id;
+----+--------+----------+---------+
| ID | Type   | capacity | status  |
+----+--------+----------+---------+
|  1 | Family |        4 | all     |
|  2 | Family |        4 | all     |
|  3 | Family |        4 | partial |
|  4 | Dual   |        2 | partial |
|  5 | Dual   |        2 | all     |
|  6 | Dual   |        2 | all     |
|  7 | Dual   |        2 | all     |
|  8 | Dual   |        2 | all     |
|  9 | Dual   |        2 | all     |
| 10 | Dual   |        2 | all     |
+----+--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: This works great, but it has one problem. When using a larger dataset than 2 (currently using 21 bookings) it produces a list of rooms containing 21 results, which show rooms as partial AND all. Im not sure what changes for this to occur

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, or ask a new one, referencing this answer.

Comment: updated question to show additional data but having issues adding data to the bookroom table within the test database atm

Comment: Found the problem preventing insertion, stray 0. Problem can now be replicated